# How to update data table in while loop?

Tags: c#

```
try
{
    string mbarcoderr;
    cm = new PgSqlCommand("SELECT linkqty,mbarcode FROM public.tb_linkproduct where barcode= '" + mbarcode + "' ", cn);
    dr = cm.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        int linkqtyy = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString());
        mbarcoderr = Convert.ToString(dr[1].ToString());

        int asd = productqty/linkqtyy;


        cm = new PgSqlCommand("update tb_product set productqty=@productqty where barcode = '" + mbarcoderr + "'", cn);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productqty",asd);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

I would like to update table via while loop but can not update?

Comment: `but can not update` so the error you are getting is?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: You haven't provided enough information in the question. Please consider adding more information as in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Update might not happen because of many reasons, could not contact the db server, db server might not be running, table might not be present ... etc.

Comment: You should rewrite this as ONE UPDATE STATEMENT using a JOIN between the tables, rather than updating the table in a loop. Also: sql injection very bad, m'kay?

Comment: @marc_s Sadly the msmvps blog site is down, I haven't had time to move my stuff elsewhere yet.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, your task is solved by a single sql update query.
You do not need to load data from the database into your application's memory for this, you do not need to perform many queries in a loop. You just need to join the two tables.

Try the following code:

```
string sql = """
    UPDATE tb_product p
    SET p.productqty = @productqty / lp.linkqty
    FROM public.tb_linkproduct lp
    WHERE lp.barcode = @barcode AND p.barcode = lp.barcode
    """;

cm = new PgSqlCommand(sql, cn);
cm.Parameters.Add("@productqty", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = productqty;
cm.Parameters.Add("@barcode", NpgsqlDbType.Integer).Value = barcode;
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Change the `NpgsqlDbType` values to the correct one (I can't know the types of your data in the tables).